# gzip table to csv on AWS instance, prior to downloading / saving locally with psql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, gzip, amazon-rds, psql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and the psql CLI. My bandwidth is extremely limited, which results in it taking hours to download each table from an AWS instance, that are 1 - 5 GB's each. The current command I use, after logging into the DB with psql:

`\copy (SELECT * FROM table) TO table.csv CSV DELIMITER ','`

Is it possible to query a table, similar to the above, that actually zips the csv file ON the Amazon PostgreSQL instance, prior to downloading and saving locally, thus reducing the 1 - 5 GB downloads to < 1 GB; significantly reducing the download times?

Something like:

`\copy (SELECT * FROM table) TO csv.zip CSV DELIMITER ',' TO table.csv.zip`

I came across this [gist](https://gist.github.com/brock/7a7a70300096632cec30), but the commands listed appear to be a complete dump of all tables / the entire db. I would like the ability to do the same for tables and subset queries.

EDIT: Solution = `\copy (SELECT * FROM table) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > Users/username/folder/folder/my_table.gz' DELIMITER ','` after logging into psql

Comment: Is it what you search? `COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > ~/my_table.zip' DELIMITER ',';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `psql` and the `STDOUT`. This command will return the output to the **client** and will compress it:

```
psql yourdb -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO STDOUT;" | gzip > output.gz
```

Or directly at the **database server** (also into a compressed file), using a client of your choice:

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > /var/lib/postgresql/my_table.gz' DELIMITER ',';
```

Comment: Thanks. When I attempted: `COPY (SELECT * FROM table) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > /my_table.gz' DELIMITER ',';` it advised me to use "\copy" instead; when I used '\copy' instead, it returned `sh: /my_table.gz: Permission denied.
could not write COPY data: Broken pipe
gzip > /my_table.gz: child process exited with exit code 1`... Is the "/var/lib/postgresql/" portion required?

Comment: Did you make sure the user postgres has permission to write in this folder?

Comment: instead of `/my_table.zip` try `/tmp/my_tyble.zip` or any other folder postgres can write in

Comment: Okay sorted; thank you so much for following up! my problem was that although I opened terminal in the specific folder I import to, which works fine without zipping, I needed to specify the full file path of that folder when zipping. e.g `\copy (SELECT * FROM table) TO PROGRAM 'gzip > Users/me/folder/folder/my_table.gz' DELIMITER ',';`