# Exporting a PostgreSQL query to a csv file using Python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, export-to-csv, psycopg2

I need to export some rows from a table in a PostgreSQL database to a .csv file using a Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, psycopg2

...

    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbname user=user password=password")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    sql = "\copy (SELECT * FROM table WHERE month=6) TO '/mnt/results/month/table.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ';';"
    cur.execute(sql)
    cur.close()

...
```

But when I run the script I get this:

```
Syntax error at or near «\»
LINE 1: \copy (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE month=6) TO '...
```

Does anyone know what can be wrong or give me a tip about?

Comment: Have you tried using quoting, so it would be \\ instead of just one \? See [this posting](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123746/list-of-escape-sequences-for-postgresql-string-data-types) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql).

Comment: Remove the `'\'`  `\copy` is a psql command, not an sql command.

Comment: check: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/72476

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `\copy` is not an SQL command, it is a command specific for the Postgres terminal client **psql** and cannot be used in this context.

Use `copy_expert(sql, file, size=8192)` instead, e.g.:

```
sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM a_table WHERE month=6) TO STDOUT WITH CSV DELIMITER ';'"
with open("/mnt/results/month/table.csv", "w") as file:
    cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
```

Read more about the function [in the documentation.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=copy_expert#cursor.copy_expert)

Comment: it doesn't store header though. To save with header sql = "COPY (SELECT * FROM tablename) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER ','  CSV HEADER;"

Answer (score 1):

`\COPY` is a [**psql command**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY) (client based) and therefore **not** a valid SQL command. Try the same simply using `COPY` (without the backslash`\`).

If you want the output file directly at the client, you might wanna use the [**STDOUT**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49000890/gzip-table-to-csv-on-aws-instance-prior-to-downloading-saving-locally-with-ps/49006009?noredirect=1#comment85132116_49006009) of `COPY`, otherwise the it will be created at the database server, which is a *luxury* not everyone has.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all statements are correct related to `\COPY` as SQL command.
If you want to try the same as you stated in the question then you can try it as a shell command in python script.

Eg:

```
import os
      
cmd1 = " Your SQL to csv Command"           
os.system(cmd1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
query = """ select * from instalacje WHERE date > '2022-02-20'"""

outputquery = "COPY ({0}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER".format(query)

with open("C:/1/Wojciech_CCC.csv", "w") as f:
    cur.copy_expert(outputquery, f)
```